# How to process 10 million records in Oracle DB using Python. (cx_Oracle / Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, cx-oracle

I tried cx_Oracle package , fetchall() , but this ended up consuming lot of RAM,
Tried Pandas as well, but that also doesn't seem to be that efficient in case we have billions of records.

My Use case - Fetch each row from oracle table to python , do some processing and load it to another table.
PS - Expecting something like fetchmany() , tried this but not able to get it work.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your tables and the processing involved it's difficult to advise you. I suggest that you **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the question tags and include the SQL statement you're running, and DDL and sample data for all tables involved. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

With your large data set, since your machine's memory is "too small", then you will have to do batch processing of sets of rows and reinsert each set before fetching the next set.

Tuning [`Cursor.arraysize`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.arraysize) and [`Cursor.prefetchrows`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.prefetchrows) (new in cx_Oracle 8) will be important for your fetch performance.  The value is used for internal buffer sizes, regardless of whether you use `fetchone()` or [`fetchmany()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.fetchmany).  See [Tuning cx_Oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html).

Use [`executemany()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.executemany) when reinserting the values, see [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).

The big question is whether you even need to fetch into Python, or whether you can do the manipulation in PL/SQL or SQL - using these two will remove the need to transfer data across the network so will be much, much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Generally your strategy should be the following.

1. Write an sql query that gets the data you want.
2. Execute the query
3. loop: Read a tuple from the result.
4. Process the tuple.
5. Write the processed stuff to the target relation

Lots of details to deal with however.

Generally when executing a query of this time, you'll want to read a version of the database. If you have simultaneous writing to the same data, you'll get a stale version, but you won't hold up the writers. If you want the most recent version, you have a hard problem to solve.

When executing step 4, don't open a new connection, reuse a connection. Opening a new connection is akin to launching a battleship.

Best if you don't have any indexes on the target relation, since you'll pay the cost of updating the target relation each time you write a tuple. It will work, but it will be slower. You can build the index after finishing the processing.

If this implementation is too slow for you, an easy way to speed things up is to process, say, 1000 tuples at once and write them in batches. If that's too slow, you've entered into the murky world of database performance tuning.

Comment: As pointed out by Jones' answer, much can be done directly inside the database. So for example, ``INSERT INTO r(a,b) SELECT c, d FROM s WHERE d>5`` copies part of relation s into r in a single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the offset-limit property. If the data can be ordered by a column (primary key or combination of columns so that the data is ordered same across the execution), heres what I tried.

I take the total count(*) of the table.
Based on a chunk size(eg:100000), create a list of values [0, 0+chunk, 0+chunk*2...count(*)].

ex: if count(*)=2222 and chunk=100, output list will be:
[0,100,200,...2222]

And then using the values of above list, I fetch each partition by using **'offset i rows fetch next j values only'**.
This will select the data in partitions without overlapping any data.

I change values of i and j in each iteration so that I get the complete data.
At a runtime, the given chunk is 100,000; that much data is loaded into memory. You can change it to any values based on  your system spec.

At each iteration, save the data wherever you want.